# Finding something's parent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a video gallery using YouTube API and I wanna make something like when you click on `<div>` where the video is, the `<div>` is gonna get bigger. Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var n,
  id = 1;
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
      part: 'snippet',
      maxResults: 15,
      channelId: 'CHANNEL_ID',
      type: 'video',
      order: 'date',
      key: 'MY_KEY'},
      function(data) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, iteam ) {
          $('#content').append('<div id="' + id + '"><br><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id.videoId + '" class="youtube"></iframe><p><font class="click">Get bigger</font></p></div>');
          $('font.click').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).parent().attr('id')); // Here I want it to write 
            //in console specific id of the
            //`<div>` I click, but it writes 15, which is 
            //the final value of `id` variable, because I 
            //click it when all the videos load. And also 
            //when I click it twice it writes 30, when 
            //thrice - 45 and etc. So I don't know how to 
            //get the specific id of the only `div` I click.
          });
          id++;
        })
      }
  );
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd very thankful for any help.

Comment: Can it be that it is just a typo?
font class="click">Get bigger</font>
it should be 
<font> class="click">Get bigger</font>

Comment: oh, that's my bad. I just rewrote it from another monitor so I could make some mistakes.

Comment: again, what about the <p> tag, you are iterating over <font> and you are expecting iframe to be its parent, right? But it looks to me that <p> is its parent.

Comment: oh, yeah <p> is its parent, but I am expecting <div> to be its parent, will `$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` work?

Comment: It should, but you can also consider removing that logic out of ajax callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a little explanation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var n,
  id = 1;
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
     part: 'snippet',
     maxResults: 15,
     channelId: 'CHANNEL_ID',
     type: 'video',
     order: 'date',
     key: 'MY_KEY'},
     function(data) {
       $.each( data.items, function( i, iteam ) {
         $('#content').append('
           <div id="googleVid-' + id + '"><br>
               <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id.videoId + '" class="youtube"></iframe>
               <p>
                    <font class="click">Get bigger</font>
               </p>
           </div>');          
           id++;
       });
     }
   ).always(function() {
       $('font.click').click(function(){
          console.log($(this).closest('div').attr('id'));
       });
   });       
});
```

1. Fixed html
2. Look what's the parent of your font. It's **p** tag not div
3. Closest instead of parent will find closest **div** tag [doc](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
4. On click event moved to document.ready

Comment: Should `.append('<div id="' + String(id) + '"` work?

Comment: `.append('<div id="myDiv-' + id + ''` should do the trick. Just add some non-numeric value before ID.

Comment: `$('#content').append('<div id="' + id + '"><br><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id.videoId + '" class="youtube"></iframe><p>font class="click">Get bigger</font></p></div>');`

Didn't looked in html before. Typo in **<**font, the parent of the <font> tag is p wich parent is your div. If you want it like that, add to <font custom attribute like:
`<font data-target="myDiv-' + id + '" class="click">Get bigger</font>` and get it in on click event with
`var id = $(this).attr('data-target');`

Comment: Thanks, but why should I create new 'id' variable if I already have one?

Comment: You didn't. It's just custom attribute with your value that you can access directly from <font> DOM object. Instead of using __.parent()__ or __closest()__ And by the var id i mean anything, you could name it however you want

Comment: oh, thanks, but I seem to have another problem: when I'm trying to click this kinda button and call the .click() event, nothing is written in console.

Comment: still have nothing in console. And even if I try just `$('font.click').click(function(){ console.log('hi'); });`, nothing happens

Comment: And that's becouse click event is attached before $.get update DOM. [$.get Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) move click block into some 'finished' promise.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: $.get(...).always is not a function"

Comment: Promise interface was introduced in jQuery 1.5, you're using 1.4.2

Comment: which version would you recommend me to use?

Comment: Latest if you don't need a specific one.

Comment: I chose 3.2.1 and now "the button" works, but it writes 'undefined'

Comment: Above example with latest jQuery works fine for me. Maybe you've changed something in your html and `$(this).closest('div').attr('id')` is wrong now.

Comment: could you, please, update your answer with html code? I'd very thankful

Comment: HTML is appended inside $.get request block. `$('#content').append('` and so on.

Comment: oh, damn, i got it, in my code i have one more `<div>` where the `<font>` is. Is there anything like .closest(), but to take the other `<div>`?

Comment: Instead of `closest('div')` you can use `closest('.class')` or chain it like: `closest('div').parent();` or `closest('div').closest('div');`

Comment: yeah, I found the way, but ty anyway

Comment: No problem, , ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$(this).parent().prev().attr('id')`

in you 'html' you have `iframe~p>font`

And $(this) refers to the `font`

Comment: or $(this).closest('div');

Comment: I'm trying to access the `div` with `.parent()`

Comment: use prev(), I updated the answer, I hope it helps you

Comment: yeah, but i have another problem: when I'm trying to click `Get bigger` which is kinda button, nothing is written in console

Comment: It might be because at the time you are attaching the event it is still not appended to the DOM. This should be another question. But you will have to wait for the element to be appended and then attach event or you can use onclick as an html attribute, how sure how it is gonna work out, really don't like how dirty it looks that way.

Comment: oh, hate this DOM, I thought `$(document).ready()` would prevent all the possible problems with it

Comment: That's why you use react, vue etc... since it will abstract away DOM traversing.
If you are dynamically adding DOM elmnts, you document.ready wont help you since it's only listening for elements that are in html file not what you are adding via js. :)

Comment: i tried to put `$('font.click').click(function(){ console.log('hi'); });` after the `<div id="content></div>"`, but still nothing in console

Comment: Please create a separate question for this one since it requires more then this comment box input :) And Please down/upvote/accept this or any other answer. :)